# using full-text search with LINQ and EF

Tags: entity-framework, full-text-search

I'm trying to implement a full-text search with EntityFramework.

My DB has a table called Users and a table called UserInfoEntries. The table users is connected to some other tables, and the table UserInfoEntries contains user information.

When i want to get the user info, i go through the entries in `User.UserInfoEntries` and get the one with the oldest entry timestamp.

The property i want to use as the key for the full-text search is the FullName property within the UserInfoEntry.

The LINQ for getting the users with the exact FullName looks like this:

```
from user in objectContext.Users

let currentInfoEntry = 
(from entry in user.UserInfoEntries
 orderby entry.EntryTimestamp descending
 select entry
).FirstOrDefault()

where currentInfoEntry.FullName == "Some Name"

select new UserWithInfo
{
    User = user,
    Info = currentInfoEntry
}
```

I would like to use the full-text search by FullName. Is there an easier way than transalting the query to SQL?

Answer (score 0):

This is not full-text search. It is just a normal search with the full match. You can simplify the query by reverting it:

```
var query = from x in objectContext.UserInfoEntries.Include("User")
            where x.FullName == "Some Name"
            orderby x.EntryTimestamp descending
            select x;

UserInfoEntry entry = query.FirstOrDefault();
User user = entry.User;
```

This query expects that your `UserInfoEntry` entity has navigation property called `User` pointing to `User` entity.

Comment: Sorry for the missunderstanding, but i was wondering how to perform a full-text search in this case. In other words how to find a user with some name using FTS. (i.e. for a keyword matt, i would like to get all the users named matt, matthew and similar).